# c++ operator overloading in derived class

Tags: c++

I'm trying to overload operator+ in a derived class.  I want to call the base operator+, but return the derived type.  What is the right way to do this?  Here is my example code.

```
class B {     // base class
public:

const B operator+( double dbl) const {
  B res;
  res.val = val + dbl;
  return res;
}
virtual void foo() {};         // make class B polymorphic
private:
double val;
}; // end class B



class D : B {     // derived class
public:

const D operator+( double dbl) const {
  // Call the base class "+".  Which is better?
  B bres1 = dynamic_cast< const B &>(*this) + dbl;
  B bres2 = B::operator+( dbl);

  // Cast the result from B to D.  But both fail.
  return dynamic_cast< D>(bres1);      // error: target is not pointer or ref
  return *(dynamic_cast< D*>(&bres1)); // error: dynamic_cast can never succeed
}
}; // end class D
```

Many thanks!

Comment: C++ does not work this way. Run a google search on "object slicing".

Comment: `Cast the result from B to D` -- In addition to what Sam pointed out, casting is **not** conversion, and you need conversion.   In other words, where is the function that takes a `B` object and actually creates a `D` object from it?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  That answers my question.  What I need is ... In B, void opAdd( double dbl) {val += dbl;}, then in D, have operator+( double dbl) { D res; res.oppAdd(dbl); return res;}.  Works!